# JavaFX Label not updating height

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a Label to display some text which is initalized with no text inside. I then add inside my main window a new node with the label inside this way :

```
    Parent root = null;
try{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/message.fxml"));
    root = loader.load();
    ObsMessage obsMessage = loader.getController();

    obsMessage.definirMessage( This is where my label's text is modified);

} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
vboxPrincipale.getChildren().add(root);`
```

So when my label is more than a few lines high, I get the following result :
[image]

I set the label's pref height to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE and Vgrow to always, as well as it's parent components. If i manually set the height of the label when I initialize the node at say 500px high, it does resize.
So Why is my label not resizing ?

Edit : The FXML file used to generate the message bubbles :

```html
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPaneMessage" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="130.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="970.0" style="-fx-background-color: WHITE; -fx-border-color: BLACK; -fx-border-width: 2;" stylesheets="@styleFenetre.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="vue.javafxobservers.ObsMessage">
   <top>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <Text fx:id="texteNom" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Prenom nom" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
            <GridPane.margin>
               <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
         </Text>
         <Text fx:id="texteDate" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Date" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
            <GridPane.margin>
               <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="10.0" top="5.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
         </Text>
      </GridPane>
   </top>
   <center>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" valignment="TOP" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <Label fx:id="texteTitre" text="Titre message" wrapText="true">
            <GridPane.margin>
               <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
         </Label>
         <Label fx:id="texteMessage" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Texte du corp du message ici..." wrapText="true" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <GridPane.margin>
               <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
         </Label>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <HBox fx:id="boxCommandes" alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <Hyperlink fx:id="linkModifier" alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" text="modifier" textFill="#0000ee" />
         <Hyperlink fx:id="linkSupprimer" alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" text="supprimer" textFill="#0000ee" />
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: We need a [mre], I’m afraid.  My first question is whether you’re setting the size of the Scene to an explicit value.  My next thought is that SceneBuilder seems to encourage people to use explicit sizes for everything, including containers.  A runnable example would answer my concerns.

Comment: @VGR a reproducible example is going to be tough to produce. Regarding you concerns, I never set a height to a certain value and the panes I display are inside a scrollPane so free space isnt an issue. I have added the code of the message bubble in my post if it helps.

Comment: If a message bubble only contains enough text to take up one line, does it have a smaller height?

Comment: @VGR You're right it doesn't have a smaller height. It only centers the line. Interesting.

Comment: @VGR After investigating it seems that my borderPane (or even the whole parent node, I'm not sure) doesn't resize at all when I set the text of my label (or anything reall) after it got initalized. Do you know how i could force it to resize ?

Comment: You’re sure there aren’t any maxHeight or prefHeight settings in the BorderPane's ancestors, up to and including the Scene?  A BorderPane certainly should accommodate the preferred size of its center node.

Comment: @VGR It is inside a gridPane which is in the center of the BorderPane, and both have USE_COMPUTED_SIZE as prefHeight and MAX_VALUE as maxHeight

Comment: And does that BorderPane have its GridPane vgrow set to ALWAYS?

Comment: @VGR I can't define a vgrow for the gridPane, but I did set its row's vgrow to always (same for the label)

Comment: _ "a reproducible example is going to be tough to produce" _ You're asking us to volunteer to solve your problem, 
 and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way I got it working properly was by using maxHeight at USE_PREF_SIZE and prefHeight at USE_COMPUTED_SIZE in **every** parent component of the Label (as well for the row of the gridPane containing the Label).

Answer (score 0):

Labels in JavaFX have a `wrapText` boolean property.

This property is set to `false` by default that's why your text which exceed the default space is being overflow with dots (...).

change this property either :

1. Programmaticaly with [setWrapText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setWrapText-boolean-)
2. With JavaFX CSS `fx-wrap-text` see [CSS Reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled)

Comment: I do use wrapText on my labels. This is why my line will break and start on another line. The issue here is that when there are too many lines, the line will stop and end with ...